# Android SeekBar [ProgressBar] style - how to set custom background drawable

Tags: android, coding-style, progress-bar, seekbar

I want to make seekbar like this: http://img687.imageshack.us/img687/2371/volumec.png
The thing is, that I`ve already found customizing seekbars over here http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/be3fed0b4f766cc?pli=1
but the problem is, that I need **those gaps** between in my drawable and I don`t know how to manage that.
Would you be so kind some of you, I`ll appreciate it very much.
Thanks in advance, wishing all the best!

this is my resources style.xml file that is applied to seekbar:

```
<item name="android:indeterminateOnly">false</item>
<item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/seekbarcolors</item>
<item name="android:indeterminateDrawable">@drawable/seekbarcolors</item>
<item name="android:minHeight">20dip</item>
<item name="android:maxHeight">20dip</item>
<item name="android:thumbOffset">8px</item>
<item name="android:focusable">true</item>
```

and here is my @drawable/seekbarcolors:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="#ff0000" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
    <clip>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#00ff00" />
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>
<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <clip>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#0000ff" />
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>
```

Answer (score 1):

A Seekbar is a pretty powerful widget.  Ddo you want the user to be able to "seek" the volume here? It's not made to show progress with gaps.

What you need here (if you don't need to grab and seek the volume) is lots simpler.  Create a single ImageView to the right of "Volume" in your sample pic. In your progress-watching AsyncTask, put code in onProgressUpdate() to change the shown image across 10 images - each the same as the last but with one more bar - as progress breaks each 10%.  You can write code to put a single image times properly positioned across a space, but that is harder and buys you little.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that i need to seek volume..as you can see, i' ve styled seekbar with my custom shape where colors are set
 Last thing i need to do is create repeatable shape with block of opacity 1 and block with opacity 0. How this can be done? I am new to android developmemt therefore not very smart with shapes :) thanks

Comment: I think that the image is effectively"stretched" across - if so SeekBar does not support gaps.  so: 1) you could try it, using an image in which the left half is light and right half dark, and simply update progress at 10% thresholds, as see if I am wrong, or 2) you could try layering a "mask" image over a seekbar that screens out gaps in the underlying progress bar.. I'm unsure on still being able to drg the progress bar, or 3) you could build a custom seekbar based on SeekBar code (Android is open source).  Good luck

Answer (score 0):

To change Volume bar colour in android In framework/core/res/res/layout change colour in volume_adjust.xml