# Customizing Default Volume bar of the device

Tags: android

In my application i am using video player in which i dont want default volume bar that will show when i press volume increase and decrease button in the device.I want a customized volume bar for my application.Any help will be appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: You want to override only the ui or the functionality too

Comment: I want same functionality but different ui

Comment: As its system UI i doubt if it can be overridden.

Comment: OnKeyDown overriden method is there but i dont know how to set the ui there.There are some code snippets to set the functionality inside that but not Ui.

Comment: You cannot modify the UI there as you do not get the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done this through by overriden method onKeyDown().Thanks for all.

Answer (score 0):

Since the volume level indicator is a system UI you cannot modify it at the application level. You could do that if you were modifying the Android OS itself.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5024399/android-seekbar-progressbar-style-how-to-set-custom-background-drawable              Check this Link.Almost like this.